# Qt: клик по всей строке в таблице

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть некоторая таблица и по клику ячейки в ней должно происходить некоторое действие и обработка данных в строке, но есть проблема. При клике я должен получить весь текст в строке целиком(допустим даже через обход строки по ячейкам), а получаю только текст с ячейки.

Вопрос:
1. Как сделать так, чтобы данные передавались со всей строки разом?
2. Как обойти строку по ячейкам?

Доп. инфо:
С Qt сталкиваюсь впервые, учусь по учебнику Макса Шлее "Qt 5.10". Версия Qt - 5.11.3

Comment: Сигнал скинь хотя бы для примера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты знаешь индекс ячейки по который произошел клик, т.е. QModelIndex, то у него есть метод row, который содержит номер строки, зная номер строки и кол-во столбцов в таблице, можно получить содержимое каждой ячейки и представить в том формате, в котором нужно.
Если ты получаешь QtableWidgetItem, то у него есть метод index(), который возвращает QModelIndex

Вот псевдокод

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < columnCount; i++) { strText += tableWidget->item(row, i)->text()}
```

Comment: т.е. иными словами я из QTableWidgetItem могу получить строку и уже от этого отталкиваться в цикле?  Причём как я посмотрю у вас нет жёсткой привязки к индексу конкретной ячейки...

Comment: в этом примере я ответил на вопрос "2. Как обойти строку по ячейкам?". У QTableWidgetItem есть метод text() который вернет текст из ячейки, пройдясь по всем ячейкам в строке, ты можешь сформировать какую угодно строку и передать ее для дальнейшей обработки

Comment: Да, я это понял. На самом деле этого решения оказалось достаточно для решения задачи №1, а потому и ответ на него уже по большому счёту и не требуется, хотя если кто-то добавит его, чтоб был, то хуже не будет.